# A Basic Question about Integrals

Tags: lebesgue-integral, riemann-integration

I have a basic question about integrals. Suppose that $f: [0,1] \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ is a bounded function. **Do not** assume that $f$ is continuous. For each $n \geq 1$, define $f_n: [0,1]\mapsto \mathbb{R}$ by:
$$f_n(x) = \sum_{j=1}^n n\int_{\frac{j-1}{n}}^{\frac{j}{n}} f(y) dy ~\mathbf{1}\left(\frac{j-1}{n}< x \leq \frac{j}{n}\right)~.$$
$f_n$ may be thought of as an $n-$step piecewise approximation of $f$. My question is:

**Is it true that $\int_0^1|f_n(x)-f(x)| dx \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$?** Also, does this answer depend on whether the integrals in question are Riemann or they are Lebesgue (in the sense of integration w.r.t. the Lebesgue measure)?

Any help will be appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: The equation for $f_n(x)$ is very confusing.  j is a dummy index, so the term with $x$ on the right is hard to understand.

Comment: @herb steinberg, when $x \in ((j-1)/n,j/n]$ $(1\leq j\leq n)$, $f_n(x) = n \int_{(j-1)/n}^{j/n} f$. Hence, $f_n$ is a step function.

Comment: And in my original post, everything (including the term in the left with the $x$ is inside the summation.

Comment: If it is Riemann integrable, using Darboux approach will give you what you need, since the upper and lower Darboux sums will bracket $f_n(x)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This reduces for a bounded Riemann integrable function to

$$\begin{align}\int_0^1 |f(x) - f_n(x)| \, dx &= \sum_{j=1}^n \int_{\frac{j-1}{n}}^{\frac{j}{n}}\left|f(x) - n\int_{\frac{j-1}{n}}^{\frac{j}{n}}f(y) \, dy  \right| \, dx \\ &= n\sum_{j=1}^n \int_{\frac{j-1}{n}}^{\frac{j}{n}}\left|\frac{f(x)}{n} - \int_{\frac{j-1}{n}}^{\frac{j}{n}}f(y) \, dy  \right|\, dx \\ &= n\sum_{j=1}^n \int_{\frac{j-1}{n}}^{\frac{j}{n}}\left|\int_{\frac{j-1}{n}}^{\frac{j}{n}}[f(x) - f(y)] \, dy  \right|\,dx \\ &\leqslant n\sum_{j=1}^n \int_{\frac{j-1}{n}}^{\frac{j}{n}}\int_{\frac{j-1}{n}}^{\frac{j}{n}}|f(x) - f(y)| \, dy \, dx  \\ &\leqslant n\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{\sup_{x,y \in \left[\frac{j-1}{n},\frac{j}{n}\right]} |f(x) - f(y)|}{n^2} \\ &= \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n \sup_{x \in \left[\frac{j-1}{n},\frac{j}{n}\right]} f(x) - \frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^n \inf_{x \in \left[\frac{j-1}{n},\frac{j}{n}\right]} f(x) \end{align}$$

The RHS is a difference of upper and lower sums which converges to $0$ as $n \to \infty$.

The steps leading to the final difference of sums are valid if $f$ is bounded and Lebesgue integrable. I'll leave it to you to determine if the limit is always $0$ in case $f$ is Lebesgue but not Riemann integrable.  Can you think of a counterexample?